# Azure web application keeps prompting for consent

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC application that will be called by both internal and external users.  This application calls an ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API, all running in the same Azure tenant.

The Web API is secured using JWT Bearer tokens.

If possible, I'd like to pass the credentials of the internal users to the Web API.  So I'm trying to use Open ID with the OAuth2 impllicit permissions grant.

I've done the following:

- Allow OAuth2 implicit flow by setting oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to True in the web application's manifest in Azure.
- Added an app role in the web API with an allowedMemberType of Application:

  ```
  "appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "Application"
    ],
    "displayName": "Access MyWeb API",
    "id": "<Guid>",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "Access MyWeb API.",
    "value": "MyWebApi.Access"
  }],
  ```
- Added a permission in the AAD Application Registration for the web application to call the wepi API - specifically the permission/role listed above.
- Granted this permissions via an Admin Consent grant (I've tried clicking the 'Grant Permissions' option in Azure, as well as an admin consent URL).
- Configured the web application to get an access token that can be used for implicit flow - that code is shown below.

Every time I log into my web application, I am getting prompted for consent:

> This app would like to:
>
> Access MyWeb API (WebAPI)
>   Access MyWeb API.
>   This is a permission
>   requested to access your data in .
>
> Sign in and read user
>   profile
>
> Allows users to sign in to the app, and allows the app to
>   read the profile of signed-in users. It also allow the app to read
>   basic company information of signed-in users.
>   This is a permission
>   requested to access your data in .

If I accept this concent, and then relaunch the application, I get prompted AGAIN; I should only have to consent once, correct?
I was trying to work with Implicit flow awhile ago, and I'm coming back to it now.  In my first attempt, I had a similar pair of applications set up like this in my tenant.  Just for grins, I modified my application and API to use the app registrations from my previous attempt, and things work PERFECTLY.  The same code, using the different app registrations, works fine.  So I must have missed a step in my Azure configuration.  Does anyone have any idea why the consent doesn't seem to be 'sticking'?

I can't simply revert back to these registrations; I will eventually have to install these in a customer's Azure, so I need to know how to set this up correctly.

I tried comparing the manifests of the old and new web application registrations and the old and new web API registrations; I didn't see anything that jumped out.

Here's the code for configuring the implicit flow, using OpenId:

```
    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureAzureAdSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return services.Configure<AzureAdSettings>(options => configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAd", options))
                       .AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureOpenIdImplicitFlowOptions<MyWebApiSettings>>();
    }
```

Here's the code in the ConfigureOpenIdImplicitFlowOptions that sets up the OpenId values;

```
    public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ResponseType = "token id_token"; 
        options.ClientId = _azureAdSettings.ClientId;
        options.Authority = $"{_azureAdSettings.Instance}{_azureAdSettings.TenantId}";
        options.CallbackPath = _azureAdSettings.CallbackPath;
        options.Resource = _implicitFlowTarget.Resource;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    }
```

I can then grab the access_token inside the web application controller to set in the header in the call to the web API.  Everything works fine after I consent - I just don't know why I have to keep giving consent.

Edit:  I'm trying to duplicate this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2017/10/04/access-an-azure-ad-secured-api-with-asp-net-core-2-0/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implicit grant flow is kinda meant for Single Page Apps. Of course I guess you can use it in back-end Web apps too. Have you tried to do the same with authorization code flow? You would have to change the response type to `code id_token`, and then override the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event to exchange the code for tokens. Tip for doing the consent nicer: modify the API's manifest so that you have `knownClientApplications: [ "your-app-client-id"]`. Put your front-end's client id there. Now you can consent to both at the same time at login.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Right after I had posted, I did a couple of things:  I tried to set up permissions for the Old App Registration to access the New API Registration, and vice-versa.  I found that if I did this, and granted permission, that I screwed up the Old Web->Old API consent.  Now it's broken too.  After I saw your reply, I did what you suggested above: using the code auth flow, and adding the App ID to the knownClientApplications.  The consent request no longer has the Api access requirement, but still has the AAD access requirement, and I'm still getting prompted for consent.